# Passing state params when navigating to a state by URL routing in angular ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, state, angular-ui-router

Below is a sample state hierarchy,

```
.state('home', {
  url: '/home',
  templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
  controller: 'HomeCtrl'
})
.state('home.books', {
  url: '/:collectionId',
  abstract: true,
  controller: 'BooksCtrl'
})
.state('home.books.displaybooks', {
  url: '^/books',
  templateUrl: 'views/displaybooks.html',
  controller: 'DisplayBookCtrl'
})
```

In home.books.displaybooks state, I display the collection of books.

I can access this state by two means,

1. By clicking on the link in "home" state. I use ui-sref and pass the default collection id for the user. No problems here
2. By URL routing http://localhost/books (please note the ^ in url in state definition. I want absolute url without displaying the collectionId in the address bar). Here the problem is that the state does not get the collectionId parameter. So can some please point how I can insert the default collectionId of the user when I am navigating to the state through URL routing.

Thanks,

Comment: Please see below answer for approval if it is useful.

Answer (score 2):

Per the [UI Router docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing)

> In state controllers, the $stateParams object will only contain the
>   params that were registered with that state. So you will not see
>   params registered on other states, including ancestors.

The work around is to use resolve in the parent route, then inject the resolved value into the child state/controller:

```
$stateProvider
.state('home', {
  url: '/home',
  templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
  controller: 'HomeCtrl'
})
.state('home.books', {
  url: '/:collectionId',
  abstract: true,
  controller: 'BooksCtrl',
  resolve:{
      collectionId: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
          return $stateParams.collectionId;
      }]
  }
})
.state('home.books.displaybooks', {
  url: '^/books',
  templateUrl: 'views/displaybooks.html',
  // controller: 'DisplayBookCtrl' // this just needs collectionId now
  controller: function($stateParams, collectionId){
       console.log(collectionId);
  }
});
```